# TimeVal Struct Seconds and Microseconds

Tags: c

How can I know the seconds and microseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 and now using timeval? Thanks.

```
struct timeval {
  long tv_sec; /*seconds since 1/1/1970*/
  long tv_usec; /*microseconds since tv_sec*/
};
```

Comment: Why do you think that `timeval` is the solution to your problem?

Comment: When you say using timeval, do you mean you want to add the seconds/microseconds from 1970 `to` timeval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you call `gettimeofday()`

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
tv.tv_sec  /* seconds */
tv.tv_usec /* microseconds */
```

However `gettimeofday()` is obsolete, the manual is recommending [clock_gettime(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) instead:

```
struct timespec tp;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
tp.tv_sec  /* seconds */
tp.tv_usec /* nanoseconds divide by 1000 to get microseconds*/
```

Comment: `struct timespec`'s second field is `tv_nsec`, not `tv_usec`.